# Receiving main.o error

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

The compiler in Qt Creator does not support c++11. So in my .pro file I added `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11`
So my .pro file now looks like this:

```
TEMPLATE = app
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.cpp \
    server.cpp \
    Section.cpp \
    mainwindow.cpp \
    main2.cpp \
    client.cpp \
    Chapter.cpp \
    Book.cpp

HEADERS += \
    Year.h \
    Term.h \
    Student.h \
    Section.h \
    mainwindow.h \
    Load.h \
    List.h \
    Course.h \
    ContentManager.h \
    client.h \
    Chapter.h \
    Book.h

OTHER_FILES += \
    Makefile \
    D2.pro.user
```

This is my makefile:

```
#############################################################################
# Makefile for building: D2
# Generated by qmake (2.01a) (Qt 4.8.1) on: Mon Nov 10 23:00:21 2014
# Project:  D2.pro
# Template: app
# Command: /usr/bin/qmake-qt4 -spec /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++ CONFIG+=debug CONFIG+=declarative_debug -o Makefile D2.pro
#############################################################################

####### Compiler, tools and options

CC            = gcc
CXX           = g++
DEFINES       = -DQT_WEBKIT
CFLAGS        = -pipe -g -Wall -W $(DEFINES)
CXXFLAGS      = -pipe -std=c++11 -g -Wall -W $(DEFINES)
INCPATH       = -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I.
LINK          = g++
LFLAGS        = 
LIBS          = $(SUBLIBS)    
AR            = ar cqs
RANLIB        = 
QMAKE         = /usr/bin/qmake-qt4
TAR           = tar -cf
COMPRESS      = gzip -9f
COPY          = cp -f
SED           = sed
COPY_FILE     = $(COPY)
COPY_DIR      = $(COPY) -r
STRIP         = strip
INSTALL_FILE  = install -m 644 -p
INSTALL_DIR   = $(COPY_DIR)
INSTALL_PROGRAM = install -m 755 -p
DEL_FILE      = rm -f
SYMLINK       = ln -f -s
DEL_DIR       = rmdir
MOVE          = mv -f
CHK_DIR_EXISTS= test -d
MKDIR         = mkdir -p

####### Output directory

OBJECTS_DIR   = ./

####### Files

SOURCES       = main.cpp \
        server.cpp \
        Section.cpp \
        mainwindow.cpp \
        main2.cpp \
        client.cpp \
        Chapter.cpp \
        Book.cpp 
OBJECTS       = main.o \
        server.o \
        Section.o \
        mainwindow.o \
        main2.o \
        client.o \
        Chapter.o \
        Book.o
DIST          = /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/common/unix.conf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/common/linux.conf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/common/gcc-base.conf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/common/gcc-base-unix.conf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/common/g++-base.conf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/common/g++-unix.conf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/qconfig.pri \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/modules/qt_webkit_version.pri \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/qt_functions.prf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/qt_config.prf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/exclusive_builds.prf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/default_pre.prf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/debug.prf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/default_post.prf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/declarative_debug.prf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/unix/gdb_dwarf_index.prf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/warn_on.prf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/resources.prf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/uic.prf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/yacc.prf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/lex.prf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/include_source_dir.prf \
        D2.pro
QMAKE_TARGET  = D2
DESTDIR       = 
TARGET        = D2

first: all
####### Implicit rules

.SUFFIXES: .o .c .cpp .cc .cxx .C

.cpp.o:
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o "$@" "$<"

.cc.o:
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o "$@" "$<"

.cxx.o:
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o "$@" "$<"

.C.o:
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o "$@" "$<"

.c.o:
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o "$@" "$<"

####### Build rules

all: Makefile $(TARGET)

$(TARGET):  $(OBJECTS)  
    $(LINK) $(LFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS) $(OBJCOMP) $(LIBS)
    { test -n "$(DESTDIR)" && DESTDIR="$(DESTDIR)" || DESTDIR=.; } && test $$(gdb --version | sed -e 's,[^0-9]\+\([0-9]\)\.\([0-9]\).*,\1\2,;q') -gt 72 && gdb --nx --batch --quiet -ex 'set confirm off' -ex "save gdb-index $$DESTDIR" -ex quit '$(TARGET)' && test -f $(TARGET).gdb-index && objcopy --add-section '.gdb_index=$(TARGET).gdb-index' --set-section-flags '.gdb_index=readonly' '$(TARGET)' '$(TARGET)' && rm -f $(TARGET).gdb-index || true

Makefile: D2.pro  /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++/qmake.conf /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/common/unix.conf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/common/linux.conf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/common/gcc-base.conf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/common/gcc-base-unix.conf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/common/g++-base.conf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/common/g++-unix.conf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/qconfig.pri \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/modules/qt_webkit_version.pri \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/qt_functions.prf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/qt_config.prf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/exclusive_builds.prf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/default_pre.prf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/debug.prf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/default_post.prf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/declarative_debug.prf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/unix/gdb_dwarf_index.prf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/warn_on.prf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/resources.prf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/uic.prf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/yacc.prf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/lex.prf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/include_source_dir.prf
    $(QMAKE) -spec /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++ CONFIG+=debug CONFIG+=declarative_debug -o Makefile D2.pro
/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/common/unix.conf:
/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/common/linux.conf:
/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/common/gcc-base.conf:
/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/common/gcc-base-unix.conf:
/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/common/g++-base.conf:
/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/common/g++-unix.conf:
/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/qconfig.pri:
/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/modules/qt_webkit_version.pri:
/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/qt_functions.prf:
/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/qt_config.prf:
/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/exclusive_builds.prf:
/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/default_pre.prf:
/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/debug.prf:
/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/default_post.prf:
/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/declarative_debug.prf:
/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/unix/gdb_dwarf_index.prf:
/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/warn_on.prf:
/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/resources.prf:
/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/uic.prf:
/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/yacc.prf:
/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/lex.prf:
/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/include_source_dir.prf:
qmake:  FORCE
    @$(QMAKE) -spec /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++ CONFIG+=debug CONFIG+=declarative_debug -o Makefile D2.pro

dist: 
    @$(CHK_DIR_EXISTS) .tmp/D21.0.0 || $(MKDIR) .tmp/D21.0.0 
    $(COPY_FILE) --parents $(SOURCES) $(DIST) .tmp/D21.0.0/ && (cd `dirname .tmp/D21.0.0` && $(TAR) D21.0.0.tar D21.0.0 && $(COMPRESS) D21.0.0.tar) && $(MOVE) `dirname .tmp/D21.0.0`/D21.0.0.tar.gz . && $(DEL_FILE) -r .tmp/D21.0.0


clean:compiler_clean 
    -$(DEL_FILE) $(OBJECTS)
    -$(DEL_FILE) *~ core *.core


####### Sub-libraries

distclean: clean
    -$(DEL_FILE) $(TARGET) 
    -$(DEL_FILE) Makefile


check: first

compiler_rcc_make_all:
compiler_rcc_clean:
compiler_uic_make_all:
compiler_uic_clean:
compiler_image_collection_make_all: qmake_image_collection.cpp
compiler_image_collection_clean:
    -$(DEL_FILE) qmake_image_collection.cpp
compiler_yacc_decl_make_all:
compiler_yacc_decl_clean:
compiler_yacc_impl_make_all:
compiler_yacc_impl_clean:
compiler_lex_make_all:
compiler_lex_clean:
compiler_clean: 

####### Compile

main.o: main.cpp Course.h \
        Year.h \
        Term.h \
        Student.h \
        ContentManager.h \
        Book.h \
        List.h \
        Chapter.h \
        Section.h \
        Load.h
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o main.o main.cpp

server.o: server.cpp 
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o server.o server.cpp

Section.o: Section.cpp Section.h
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o Section.o Section.cpp

mainwindow.o: mainwindow.cpp mainwindow.h \
        client.h
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o mainwindow.o mainwindow.cpp

main2.o: main2.cpp mainwindow.h \
        client.h
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o main2.o main2.cpp

client.o: client.cpp client.h
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o client.o client.cpp

Chapter.o: Chapter.cpp Chapter.h \
        List.h \
        Section.h
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o Chapter.o Chapter.cpp

Book.o: Book.cpp Book.h \
        List.h \
        Chapter.h \
        Section.h
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o Book.o Book.cpp

####### Install

install:   FORCE

uninstall:   FORCE

FORCE:
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting this error:  `[main.o] Error 1`

This error was non-existent before adding c++11. I can't solve this problem. Can someone please help me here?

UPDATE:
Typing in gcc -v in the command line in Qt creator gave me:

```
Starting command 'gcc -v'
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/usr/bin/gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/lto-wrapper
Target: i686-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.6/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.6 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.6 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-plugin --enable-objc-gc --enable-targets=all --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=i686-linux-gnu --host=i686-linux-gnu --target=i686-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 

'gcc -v' finished
```

I think the compiler version is 4.6.3, which means it supports C++11

Comment: 1. Did you tried to clean before make? 2. Are you sure no other error before that `Error 1`?

Comment: "Qt" does not include a C++ compiler. You may be referring to Qt Creator, which is an IDE that can use a C++ compiler. Either way, you need to figure out which C++ compiler/version you are actually using. If the one you are using is old and does not support C++11, adding a `-std=c++11` flag won't help - it'll just be an unrecognized flag.

Comment: Also, there should be more context to that error message. Post it.

Comment: @AndrewMedico 1. How do I know which version I'm using? I was able to know it didn't support some functions that are available in c++11. 2. How do I make the IDE support c++11?  3.That was the only error - exactly as I posted.

Comment: @SHR I've cleaned before make and it is still giving me the same error - the only error

Comment: You might try adding `CONFIG += c++11` to your project file instead.  That is the usual way to add support for c++11.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I tried doing that but it did not support the functions in c++11. The main.o error didn't come up though

Comment: What is the version of g++ you're actually using?

Comment: @RetiredNinja while checking the options in Qt creator, I saw that it has a compiler path of usr/bin/g++. That is all I got. I don't know how to check the version

Comment: You need to type `gcc -v` in a shell and edit the results into your question.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I've added the results to the question

Comment: There's some information about the flags and features that gcc 4.6.3 supports here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17378969/how-to-change-gcc-compiler-to-c11-on-ubuntu  You should probably try just compiling a simple hello word program from the command line with the different flags to see what works and then add that to the QMAKE_CXXFLAGS in your .pro file.  You might also consider trying to upgrade the compiler.

Comment: In Qt Creator, try looking at the *Compile Output* to get the original error message shown in *Issues*. There has to be a better error than just `Error 1`....

Answer (score 0):

There's more to that error message than just `[main.o] Error 1`. Paste the whole error message.

However, some guesses as to your problem might include:

- You use both `$(OBJCOMP)` and `$(SUBLIBS)` in your linker command, but neither of them is defined anywhere. Could this be the cause of the error?
- Some old versions of g++ (for example, 4.6.3) spell the option `-std=c++0x` instead of `-std=c++11`. Depending on the output of `g++ --version`, you might need to use the older spelling.
- You might need to add `-std=c++11` to the `LFLAGS` as well as to the `CXXFLAGS`, to make sure that you're linking against the correct C++ library. (I don't know of any systems for which this matters, but I always try to get it right anyway.)

Comment: Believe me, that was the only error. I tried all your suggestions but none could solve the problem, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

I got this error a few times as well.
I was frankly amazed at the lack of information in the error message, well, I mean, there is basically none.

Here is my interpretation of what the erro means:
**main.o doesn't exist / can't be found / is entirely broken.**

There are a few ways you could've ended up in this situation:

- Location where main.o is supposed to be written is write protected.    (You could try toggling shadowbuild in Qt creator)
- You're out of space (I know, sounds absurd with 8TB HDDs on the market. This was what was happening for me tho.)
- Your project is ill configured.    (Sometimes there is a difference between / and \ in paths)
- Your compiler is ill configured.
- There is something very wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0):

> Unfortunately, I'm getting this error:  [main.o] Error 1
>   ..... 
>   Believe me, that was the only error. I tried all your suggestions but none could solve the problem, unfortunately

Interestingly, **Qt Creator** does not remove your project's `Makefile` even if you do *Cleaning* and *Rebuilding*.

Those options does remove your output binary files (including `.o` files), but sometimes it can't be sufficient especially when you're editing the `.pro` file or `.qrc` file.

In most cases where the build error message is unclear and it's claimed, *"Well it just worked before!"* it's worth trying making sure that you're building it completely from the scratch all the way through by:

1. Going to your build directory such as:

   ```
   ../build-*
   ```
2. Deleting all relevant `Makefile` scripts and others if necessary,
3. Then re-building it again.